# Jquery - Accessing input element within a class by its index

Tags: jquery

I need some pointer here. I am trying to set the value of multiple input text within a class by its index value. The extra validate class is just for inline form validation and I think it is not the problem.

I was able to access multiple check boxes within a class using the same method but I can't figure this one out. Can someone please give me a hint as to what I did wrong? Thank you.

**Script**

```
//--(4) Load Delivery Cost Input Box
var tmpstr = $('#editDeliveryCost').html();
if (tmpstr != ""){
   var tmparray = tmpstr.split(',');
   for (i = 0; i < tmparray.length; ++i) {
      $('.typeDeliveryCost:eq('+(tmparray[i]-1)+')').val(tmparray[i]);
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name='cost[]' id='inp01' class="validate[required,custom[price]] typeDeliveryCost" />
<input type="text" name='cost[]' id='inp02' class="validate[required,custom[price]] typeDeliveryCost" />
<input type="text" name='cost[]' id='inp03' class="validate[required,custom[price]] typeDeliveryCost" />
<input type="text" name='cost[]' id='inp04' class="validate[required,custom[price]] typeDeliveryCost" />
```

Comment: What output are you getting now?  Do you get any errors?  Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the problem?

Comment: What is the value of `tmpstr`? How about a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net)? Side note, you should really be more consistent with using single/double quotes in both markup (delimiting attributes) and in JS (delimiting strings).

Comment: I have checked that the array are containing the right data I wanted so there are no issue with tmpstr or tmparray.

Comment: @mellamokb : I am getting nothing in the input boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$('.typeDeliveryCost:eq('+(tmparray[i]-1)+')').val(tmparray[i]);
```

to

```
$('.typeDeliveryCost:eq(' + i + ')').val(tmparray[i]);
```

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake on assigning the index to the array value, silly me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt

```
$('.typeDeliveryCost:eq('+(tmparray[i]-1)+')').val(tmparray[i]);
```

be

```
$('.typeDeliveryCost:eq(' + i + ')').val(tmparray[i]);
```

`:eq(index)` takes a zero-based index ([eq-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/))